# How do I record PC audio output without using any external program?

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to making a screen recorder program, and I also want to record the audio output.

I found a few other questions which had the same problem as mine, and the solutions were either outdated or they didn't work on my current computer.

Most solutions I found used VB-AUDIO cable to loopback audio, but I don't want my program to rely on other applications for it to function.

Is there any library I can use which has a proper loopback function that can be used to record and save computer audio output?

Comment: Asking about any specific libary or *for opinion-based answer* is against SO. Please read [what type of question should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and edit your question accordingly!

Comment: I'm not asking about a specific library, I'm searching for a library which I could use to solve my problem.

Comment: @leaves that sounds like asking for a specific library, because only a specific library can accomplish this task, otherwise You could do it with any other library, couldn't You? since You can't do it with any other library, it means that the library is pretty specific, therefore You are asking for suggestions, which is against SO or sth, basically You are asking for any library that can specifically solve Your issue, anyways, did You try searching on google?

Comment: @Matiis Yes I did, I found about 5 stackoverflow answers and none solved my problem as most were either outdated or were for Linux or used external programs, whereas I use Windows and I don't want to use external programs

Comment: You will likely need to install vendor specific audio drivers for your audio chipset rather than the generic drivers that Microsoft provides. you then should be able to select the "stereo mix" (at least that's what mine is called with a realtek audio chip on my motherboard) input source to record via one of the python libraries for port audio (`pyaudio`, `pastream`, `sounddevice`, etc..)